# JQueryMobile - Dynamicly load page before transition

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, jquery-mobile, transition

im currently experimenting with a jquerymobile + phonegap app. My question focuses on the jquerymobile framework.

I want to change to a page that is dynamically (via jsonp) loaded with a slidefade transition and I want to see the loaded content in the transition. Currently it is doing the transition and afterwards the content is shown. (Because I'm using the pagebeforeshow event to add the data to the dom.)

I loaded the content via jsonp before triggering the changePage event. So my data is already there. Now I need to put that data in the dom before performing the transition. I tried to find the right position in the changePage function of jqm to trigger an event and triggerd it before the transition. But the content isn't shown inside the transition.

Thats how i load my list (That works fine)

```
function getList() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show');
    var req = $.ajax({
    url : serviceURL + 'canteenParser2.php?type=getAllCanteens&callback=?',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    async : false,
    cache: false,
    timeout : 10000
});

req.success(function(data) {
    globalAjaxData = data;
    $.mobile.changePage('mensa.html',{showLoadMsg: false,
                         transition: 'slidefade'}
    );

});

req.error(function() {
    alert('Oh noes!');
});
}
```

And thats how i show the data:

```
function showList()
{
mensaList = globalAjaxData;
$.each(mensaList, function(index, mensa) {
    $('#mensaList').append('<li><a href="mensadetails.html?id=' + mensa.id + '" data-transition="slidefade">' +
                '' + mensa.name +  '</a></li>');
    });
$('#mensaList').listview('refresh');

}
```

I'm currently calling the showList() methode with:

```
$('#mensaListPage').live('pageshow',function(event){
    showList();
});
```

As I mentioned I tried for example the pageload event and the pagebeforeshow event.
Has anyone a suggestion how to implement the desired behavior?

Greetings
Moritz

**UPDATE**

I figured out that I need to call the showList Methode after the ajax loading call, before the transition:

```
$$('#mensaListPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event){
showList();
});
```

Thats working for the slide transition, but not for the slidefade transition. (But the slide transition ends up with flickering in my mobile app. Because of that I used the slidefade.)

Hopefully there is a chance to solve one of the problems. ;)

Comment: In your req.success function can you call showList before calling changePage()?  This should ensure the page is updated before it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonp` requests do not support synchronous operation,

load your data in second page.it will work well.